# Add This Integration With rails turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, addthis, turbolinks

I am trying to integrate [addthis](http://www.addthis.com) (smartlayers) js to my rails 4 application

i added the code on two pages eg(show template, edit template)

when i navigate from one page to another page using the links i cannot see the icons working

when i refresh the page i can able to see the icons. and i googled and i found out on rails the pages use turbolinks to navigate.

i have tried the solutions from [this](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/262) but can't solve it.

Here is my edit template

```
    <h1>Editing product</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @product %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
<!-- Go to http://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers to customize -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5270a69567915956"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  addthis.layers();
</script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

and my show template

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
<%= image_tag @product.photo.url(:medium) %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @product.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Sku:</strong>
  <%= @product.sku %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @product.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Price:</strong>
  <%= @product.price %>
</p>


<%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(:product_id => @product), :class =>"btn btn-success" %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>

<!-- AddThis Smart Layers BEGIN -->
<!-- Go to http://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers to customize -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5270a69567915956"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  addthis.layers();
</script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, it's because Turbolinks isn't fully reloading the page, it's only grabbing the body, so you're JS or CoffeeScript isn't loading on the new page.

**To fix:**

Put `ready = ->` at the top of your CoffeeScript file and put `$(document).ready(ready) $(document).on('page:load', ready)` at the end of the file.

**Like this:**

```
ready = ->
.
.
.
$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

You can read about the code on the [Turbolinks GitHub](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#events).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I use this same strategy for others(eg:google analytics) which is working but it is not working for the addthis smartlayers

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all the relevant code for AddThis?